# invalid command name "tk"

Tags: python, mercurial, tcl, tk-toolkit

I tried running the command "hg view" from HgkExtension and got an error 'invalid command name "tk"'. I'm wondering what software package is missing in my system (which is running Fedora Linux). Thanks!

And could some one please tell me which rpm package this command is from? Thanks!

Comment: You should look into some of the more modern graphical tools for Mercurial: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OtherTools TortoiseHg is probably the most widely used and it works on all three major platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing [Tcl/Tk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl). Also see [Sourceforge.net](http://tcl.sourceforge.net/)

Here's a [fedora related announcement](http://osdir.com/ml/fedora-announce/2011-11/msg00893.html), perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum install tkinter
```

should install tkinter, tix and tk